# test build agents of a build controller using tfs api

Tags: c#, tfs, tfsbuild

I want to automate testing of newly created build agents in TFS.

Now, I have written code to queue builds of particular build definition on TFS.

Problem I am facing is to queue build definition on agents of given controller.

Previously there was one method which I've commented in my code
for doing this, i.e. `IbuildRequest.buildagent`, but now it has been deprecated in newer tfs api.

Edit:
I have already tested IbuildRequest.BuildController property which tends to randomly pick agent, which is currently free. 
What I want to know is can I force build definition to use one build Agent using tfs api.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client;

namespace BuildAgentsTestApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Uri collectionURI = new Uri("https://tfs-uri");
            var tfsCreds = new TfsClientCredentials(new WindowsCredential(), true);
            TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(collectionURI,tfsCreds);
            WindowsIdentity user = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
            tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();
            if (tfs.HasAuthenticated)
            {
                WorkItemStore workItemStore = tfs.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
                Project teamProject = workItemStore.Projects["myProjectName"];
                IBuildServer buildServer = (IBuildServer)tfs.GetService(typeof(IBuildServer));
                IBuildDefinition buildDef = buildServer.GetBuildDefinition(teamProject.Name, "myBuildDefinitionName");

                var controller = GetRequestedController(buildServer, "myControllerName");
                var AgentsList = GetAgentCollection(controller);

                //Queue each build definition
                IBuildRequest buildRequest = buildDef.CreateBuildRequest();
                buildRequest.GetOption = GetOption.Custom;

                //buildRequest.BuildAgent = AgentsList.First();
                buildServer.QueueBuild(buildRequest);

            }
            Console.WriteLine("Build Queued!");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static IBuildController GetRequestedController(IBuildServer reqBuildServer, string reqControllerName)
        {
            var requiredController = reqBuildServer.QueryBuildControllers()
                                        .Where(ctrl =>
                                                ctrl.Name == reqControllerName
                                                ).FirstOrDefault();
            return requiredController;
        }

        static List<IBuildAgent> GetAgentCollection(IBuildController controller)
        {
            var ListOfAgents = from agent in controller.Agents
                               select agent;
            return ListOfAgents.ToList();
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: The message about it being depreciated says how to fix it.  "This property has been deprecated. Please remove all references. Use the BuildController property instead."  So... use the `BuildController` property.

Comment: The problem with using build controller property is it will randomly select build agent,which I don`t want.It is same as giving " * " in build agent name.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include that information.  It will ensure that the answers that eventually come, aren't just variants on the comment I made.  It also allows people answering to address the actual issue, that is, that the replacement property doesn't appear to solve your problem.